# Accounting for the nonlinear behaviour of a binary predictor

Tags: categorical-data, nonlinear

I have a continuous response variable $Y$ that I have broken down into four categories, {Low, Medium, High, Very High}. I'd like to model $Y$ against a binary variable $X$. Calculating the proportion of $X=1$ for each of the four categories, I notice that the proportion of $X=1$ is low in the first and last category (Low and Very High), but higher in the middle categories (Medium and High).

[image: proportion of x=1 for each response category]

So clearly $X=1$ is more predictive of a Medium or High response. I'd like to somehow account for this in any models I run, as I feel it is important to be able to adjust for the effect of this variable when adding further predictors into the model.

I understand the polr function in R assumes that the proportion of $X=1$ moves linearly as I move linearly between the response categories, so I'm uncertain as to what type of model I can use instead.

My question is: what can be done to account for the nonlinear behaviour of x? And what kind of packages in R handle these kind of models?

Comment: Why did you categorize a continuous variable?

Comment: Mainly because the response is not normal, or easily transformed to become normal (around half the variable is near zero, the rest is heavily skewed). Splitting up the variable in this way also made it much more clear to me that my predictor is behaving in this nonlinear fashion.

Comment: It may be useful for demonstrating the nonlinearity but it is not good for modeling purposes.

Comment: Noted :). Although unfortunately I'm not sure how to proceed either way in this case...

Comment: Nor am I. Very interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about quantile regression? The key is that you have to adjust the modeling of the DV not the IV

e.g.

```
set.seed(192981)
#Generate data 
y <- c(rnorm(250,10,2), rnorm(250,15,2),rnorm(250,20,2),
       rnorm(250,10,2))
x <- c(rep(0,125),rep(1,125),rep(0,50),rep(1,200),
       rep(0,100),rep(1,150),rep(0,200),rep(1,50))
#Quantile regression
library(quantreg)
taus <- seq(.1, .9, by = .1)
m1 <- rq(y~x,tau = taus)
m1
```

this generates some warnings, but I think that is because of how I set up the data. With real data, I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I got the warning with my data, but it disappeared when I added in method="fn", even though it doesn't seem to make much difference to the results.

Defining linear models over the quantiles seems like a really nice approach and easy to interpret - eyeballing the summaries over the increasing quantiles I initially get a positive slope for x, then a flat slope in the middle, then a decreasing slope, exactly as I'd expect. 

Thanks for the idea, this is probably a good way forward and I never would have thought of it myself. Will read up on it :)